# Dynamic linking of tables in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to make tables link to the back end in Access 2010 at startup,

Here is the code:

```
dbs.TableDefs(intLoop - 1).Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strBack & strBackEnd
Debug.Print (dbs.TableDefs(intLoop - 1).Connect)
dbs.TableDefs(intLoop - 1).RefreshLink
```

now the connect is to a file on the C: or D: drive depending on the PC setup.  But instead of connecting to the file it opens the system DNS selector window.

Any clues as to why?  The path is valid, the database is valid.

Comment: What do `strBack & strBackEnd` output? Are they respectively directory and base names with forward slash Windows separator and extension?

Comment: yes, the string is a valid path to a valid mdb file. It's the RefreshLink thet opens the dsn window

Comment: The only reason a DSN setup would launch is if an ODBC linked table (a non-Access source) is used.

Comment: Yes Parfait,  That was dumb of me, a case of cant see the wood for the trees.  The database has a mix of local tables, linked to mdb files and links to SQLServer.  I was focusing on the local mdb issue and just didn't think about the SQL links.  Thanks.  It's a total mess I inherited, originally built on access 97 but of course the company doesn't want to update things, just keep adding onto a crumbling foundation :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment you explained:

> The database has a mix of local tables, linked to mdb files and links
>   to SQLServer.

You can deal with that mix by checking the `.Connect` property of each `TableDef` and altering only those which are links to another Access database.

```vb
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

Set dbs = CurrentDb
For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
    With tdf
        If .Connect Like ";DATABASE=*" Then
            .Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strBack & strBackEnd
            .RefreshLink
        End If
    End With
Next
```

That suggestion assumes the links already exist and you're only trying to alter their connection properties.  If you need to create the links from scratch, include a local table with the information for each linked table, and drive the link creation using that information.

Comment: Thanks, once I released my mistake I had this sorted, but I will mark this as the answer for others who may wander down the same path,